# Why is there a disconnect between Luisa Rey and the other reincarnations?

Tags: cloud-atlas

I am specifically speaking about the novel here, rather than the movie of the same name, although I doubt there is a difference between the two. All of the other characters in the novel appear to be actual reincarnations of the same people. However, Luisa Rey isn't really the same - she's actually a fictional character from a novel by Hilary V. Hush. (Timothy Cavendish recounts the novel, and actually is in the process of editing it when his ghastly ordeal takes place).

This seems like a disconnect to me - all of the other versions of the reincarnation of the Timothy Cavendish/Sonmi-451/Adam Ewing character seem to exist in another world - namely the universe of the "real" within the novel. There must be a reason for this - Luisa Rey exists within her own world and timeline, but is actually reincarnations of the other versions of the character. Does this indicate a connection between Hilary V. Hush and the other reincarnations, given that she creates this version of the character?

Comment: I always interpreted the book Cavendish was editing as a retelling of the events that happened to Hilary Hush.

Comment: @Robbert That could be true, but what baffles me is that she bills it as "The First Luisa Rey Mystery," which seems to indicate there was the intent for others. I think Timothy Cavendish also discusses that it's fiction (and, I think, initially, that it's not up to his expectations, at least before the ghastly ordeal).